# What version of ANT is being used by the antrun plugin

Tags: ant, maven, maven-ant-tasks

What version of ANT is being used by the [antrun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin and how do I control it to use a certain version of ANT distribution. Does this plugin actually pick up the ANT from the local distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information in Maven Central it's using Ant 1.8.1.

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.maven.plugins|maven-antrun-plugin|1.6|maven-plugin

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.ant|ant-nodeps|1.8.1|jar

Comment: Using the antrun plugin version 1.8 uses ant 1.9.4

Comment: Can always being checked on the doc site of the plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/dependencies.html